# Strange behaviour of enumerate in IPython

Tags: python-2.7, ipython, enumerate

I appear to be experiencing some strange behaviour in IPython shell, and Notebook with regard to enumerate object, or I am not understanding something. In particular I can only get output for the following when I call the enumerate function inside the operation. I cannot create an enumerate object and then get output based on that, is this normal?

The set up:

```
In [1]: ee_cummings = ['sun', 'moon', 'stars', 'rain']
In [2]: enumerate_object = enumerate(ee_cummings)
In [3]: list(enumerate_object)
Out[3]: [(0, 'sun'), (1, 'moon'), (2, 'stars'), (3, 'rain')]
```

Now the following give me no output whatsoever:

```
In [4]: for tup in enumerate_object:
            print tup
In [5]: [index for index, element in enumerate_object]
```

But the following do give the expected output:

```
In [6]: for tup in enumerate(ee_cummings):
             print tup
        (0, 'sun')
        (1, 'moon')
        (2, 'stars')
        (3, 'rain')
In [7]: [index for index, element in enumerate(ee_cummings)]
Out[7]: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Is there something about the enumerate object that I am missing that does not allow it to be assigned in this manner?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't ipython, it's python. `enumerate` returns a generator, you only get to iterate that once! Instead of trying to reuse it, just write `enumerate(ee_cummings)` each time.

Comment: how awful to be such an ephemeral object! It seems strange that the namespace of the object is preserved. If there a reason for that? Thanks

Comment: Generators are actually quite nice in practice, for instance I can write `for i, p in enumerate(it.permutations(range(20)))` without worrying about killing my memory. Persistent generators are only really useful for tiny lists. It is a gotcha starting out, I agree, but I'm sure you'll be won over :)